# Adding file to hive partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, apache-hive

Until hive 0.13 version I was able to add a file to a particular partition of a hive table using the below command :

```
alter table table add partition (year=2016,month=07,day=25,file_part=1) location '/home/user/data/201607/NetworkActivity_553_1051924_07-25-2016.log.gz';
```

Our cluster got updated and hive is now hive 1.2 version. I am unable to execute the above command as it throws out the below error :

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:maprfs:/home/user/data/201607/NetworkActivity_553_1051924_07-25-2016.log.g is not a directory or unable to create one)
```

Could you please let me know that from hive 1.2 version we can only add directories to partition?

Comment: can you able to do select from table ..

Comment: can you able to do select from table ..  most likely your meta is outdated..

Answer (score 0):

Partition location should be directory. Create partition with location=some_directory first then put files into directory. Or put files into some directory then alter table add partition with location = directory.

In your example this is like this:

```
alter table table add partition (year=2016,month=07,day=25,file_part=1) location '/home/user/data/201607';
```

Comment: I just want to know if there has been a change from hive 0.13 version to hive 1.2 version. As I have mentioned in the question I was able to add files in particular to a partition , which right now I am not able to due to version change.

Comment: As far as I know It was always the same. Before .13 version and after. Partition is a folder. I'm working on Hortonworks. Probably it was a bug in your previous Hive version that allowed you to add files instead of folders.

Comment: @KSNidhin: have you tried the approach suggested by @leftjoin? Is it working ?